# How to select first item in nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which is described below___

```
dict = {
  "Moli": {
    "Buy": 75,
    "Sell": 53,
    "Quantity": 300
  }
  "Anna": "Buy": 55,
  "Sell": 83,
  "Quantity": 154
}
"Bob": {
  "Buy": 25,
  "Sell": 33,
  "Quantity": 100
}
"Annie": {
  "Buy": 74,
  "Sell": 83,
  "Quantity": 96
}}
```

I want to select first item `i.e: "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300}` from this nested dictionary in python

I will be very grateful if someone tells me how to do this :) :) :)

Comment: You can use `dict.keys()[0]` and `dict.values()[0]` but a dictionary is the wrong data structure for this type of thing. A list would be more suitable.

Comment: like @BHISM NARAYAN said: a dictionary is not subscriptable. `dict.keys()[0]` will give `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`. first converting to `list` and then indexing with numbers is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy (but don't use `dict` as variable name) :

```
print(myDict[(list(myDict.keys())[0])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get items based on index from dictionary .However you can convert your dictionary to list and get first item like this.

```
list(dict.items())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_dict = {
    "Moli": {
        "Buy": 75,
        "Sell": 53,
        "Quantity": 300},
    "Anna": {
        "Buy": 55,
        "Sell": 83,
        "Quantity": 154},
    "Bob": {
        "Buy": 25,
        "Sell": 33,
        "Quantity": 100},
    "Annie": {
        "Buy": 74,
        "Sell": 83,
        "Quantity": 96}
}
print(some_dict['Moli'])
print(some_dict.keys())
print(some_dict.values())
print(some_dict.items())
```

Hopefully this helps!